# Where is react documentation for setstate ?”

Tags: reactjs

I’m trying to learn react and was wondering where in the react documentation is using a callback function with setstate described? Specifically the part that explains what the arguments to the callback are? The first argument being state and the second being props?

Comment: You are right, [the `setState` documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) is not clear. This is all it says about `callback`: “The second parameter to `setState()` is an optional callback function that will be executed once `setState` is completed and the component is re-rendered.” Since it doesn’t mention what arguments the callback is passed, I would assume it is passed none, but you can’t be sure without looking inside the React code.

Comment: DCR, your question probably wouldn't have been downvoted if it had included a link to the `setState` documentation and quoted the sentence describing the `callback`. That would have proved that you had tried to answer the question yourself first, and prevented people from assuming you didn't know where the documentation was and thus giving you an incomplete answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) is the official documentation

Comment: It does not describe the parameters of the callback though, only mentions there is a callback.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't all that information listed [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate)?